# Concise way to test if X is within the bounds of Y +/- small tolerance?

Tags: r

Is there a concise way to test whether some number X is within the bounds of another number Y plus or minus some small tolerance?

Comment: so something like `Y-t <= X <= Y+t` or `abs(Y-X) <= t`?

Comment: correct.  Wondering if there's a built-in function that does this.  Something like InBounds( X , Y , .000001 ).  I was going to use the abs(...) approach but wanted to check if there was a friendly function for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `all.equal` command allows for a `tolerance` parameter so that differences less than the tolerance value are ignored.

Personally, I am rather fond of `all.equal` as an alternative to `identical`, as it is far more informative.  It is applicable to objects that are more general than just a single value (e.g. variable1 and variable2), such as data frames, lists, and more.  So, although it will do the trick for your question, it is also more general for when you would like to consider whether two data frames are *very nearly* the same.  This is quite useful when the differences are based on issues in numerical precision very close to the machine tolerance.

Comment: thanks!  Checked out all.equal, and it doesn't seem appropriate for if statements because the FALSE case is returned as a string with the mean relative difference (which is pretty cool info)

Comment: also, identical doesn't seem to have tolerance?

Comment: @SFun28: for an `if` statement, wrap `all.equal` with `isTRUE`, and no, `identical` doesn't have tolerance; it tests for identicality, not equality (if that makes any sense).

Comment: FWIW,  all.equal vs. identical vs. ==  is covered extensively in the R-FAQ over at CRAN headquarters.